# How to update a REST Resource with Spring Data Rest that has a OneToMany and nested a ManyToOne relation

Tags: spring, rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a simple Invoice System where I need to create and update Invoices. I'm trying to use Spring Data Rest for that, but from what I get from the docs I really would end up doing a lot of calls to implement an update.

[image: Invoice Model]

```
@Entity
class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long ID;
    @Basic
    String name;
}
@Entity
class Invoice {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long ID;
    @Basic
    String customer;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    List<InvoiceItem> items;

}
@Entity
class InvoiceItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long ID;
    @Basic
    double amount;
    @ManyToOne
    private Article article;
}
```

I'm using Spring Data Rest to expose this model to my web fronend via these Spring Data Rest/JPA Repositories

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "articles", path = "articles")
interface ArticleJPARepository extends JpaRepository<Article, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "invoices", path = "invoices")
interface InvoiceJPARepository extends JpaRepository<Invoice, Long> {}

@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "invoiceitems", path = "invoiceitems")
interface InvoiceItemJPARepository extends JpaRepository<InvoiceItem, Long> {}
```

So let's say I have an update form that looks like this:

[image]

where I can do several things:

- Update Invoice customer
- Change an Article of an existing InvoiceItem
- Remove some of the InvoiceItems
- Append a new InvoiceItem

From what I get from the Spring Rest Docs is that I need to make several calls now.

1. Update of the invoice customer I need to `PUT /invoices/1`
2. then update **n** the Article and amount in an InvoiceItem PUT **n** times `PUT /invoiceitems/<x>/`
3. Append **m** new InvoiceItems **m** times `POST /invoiceitems` then `POST /invoices/1/items`
4. Delete InvoiceItem 2 `DELETE /invoiceitems/2` and then `DELETE /invoices/1/items/<2>`

Is there a simpler way to realise such an update with Spring Data Rest?

Comment: Hi @maxb. I know that a lot of time has passed but did you find a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Hi, not really. In general I think there is a conceptual issue with my case as I expose the InvoiceItems as a resource. It maybe better to expose only the invoice as resource and treat the items as a value object nested in the invoices. If I would do this I think the whole rest part would get easier but of course it is harder to implement if you want to store your items in a separate db table

Comment: Thank you! I finally gave up using Spring Data Rest and used my own controller. I In my case, HAL isn't a requirement so a simple json interface is simpler to use and maintain.